# Is closing the window of a X client application process necessarily followed by terminating the process?

Tags: x11, process, window

When the window of a X client application is closed, is that necessarily followed by terminating the application process (only attempt to terminate, regardless of success of failure)?

When that is followed by terminating the application process, how is the process notified to terminate? By some signal whose default action is to terminate the process, and if yes, what sends the signal?

Thanks.

Comment: It will receive a message through its connection to X server, depending on how you connect to it, it might be UDS or TCP socket. X server sends it. Of cource, you can always ignore it.

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr;** the X11 protocol has no idea of processes, signals or any kind of IPC; both the server and any of its clients may be on different machines and operating system, which may simply have no concept of processes at all (at the time the X11 protocol was designed, Lisp machines were still a thing). The X11 itself protocol may run on top of unix sockets, tcp/ip or be tunneled through ssh, etc.

There are 3 ways to "close" an X11 window:

1. Send a `ClientMessage` event with the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` atom to that window. The application that created that window may act on it (eg. `xclock`, `xeyes` will just exit; other may close that window and continue running) or may ignore it. This is what typically happens when you press the `X` button or press some "standard" key combo like `Alt-F4`.
2. Forcefully destroy that window with `XDestroyWindow`. The app may not expect it and may ignore any `DestroyNotify` event, and still try to do operations on that window as if it were still existing, which will cause it to receive an `XErrorEvent` with its code set to `BadWindow`. The default error handler from Xlib (set with `XSetErrorHandler`) will print an error message and do a clean `exit(3)` in that case.
3. Call `XKillClient` on that window, which will forcefully close the client which has created it (instead of a window you can use any X11 resource, eg. the `XID` of a pixmap). This is what `xkill(1)` does [1]. This has nothing to do with `kill(2)` or `kill(1)` and does not send any signal to any process. Unless the client has taken special measures (see `XSetCloseDownMode(3)`) all the resources it has created (windows, pixmaps, graphic contexts) will be destroyed. Again, the default Xlib *io* error handler (set with `XSetIOErrorHandler`) will print an error message and do a clean `exit(3)` in this case, too. The difference from pt. 2. is that the handler set with `XSetIOErrorHandler` can**not** return.

Some apps quite annoyingly treat 2. and 3. as a "crash" (eg. firefox which will show its infamous "Well this is embarasssing" message on the next start, unless `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` is set to false).

Also, an app has no way to know if it was kicked out the server with `XKillClient` or if the server itself has closed unexpectedly or crashed.

Another thing that it's worth rehashing is that the X11 protocol is *cooperative* by design; there are no barriers and checks between X11 clients; any client can kick any other client out with `XKillClient`, destroy or resize its windows, grab the keyboard or mouse all to itself, set the override redirect flag to get the window manager out of the way, etc.

[1] unless you're using a *reparenting* wm, you should use `xkill -frame` for it to work.

Answer (score 4):

First, X clients can open multiple windows; "the" window of an X client doesn't exist.

The (client-side) Xlib function [xdestroywindow](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xdestroywindow), which can also be called by the window manager (WM), tells the X server to destroy a particular window. The X server then removes this windows from its internal data structures and sends a `DestroyNotify` event to the client. The client can process this event, for example to decrease a counter of currently used windows etc.

Bascially all X toolkit libraries provide some kind of main event loop and some way to exit this main loop. For example, the Xt toolkit has `XtAppMainLoop`, and the man page says

> Applications can provide their own version of this loop, which tests
>     some global termination flag or tests that the number of top-level wid‐
>     gets is larger than zero before circling back to the call to `XtAppNext`‐
>     Event.

So the application has to be programmed correctly to terminate; nothing stops it from keeping running with no windows at all. In fact, some X commandline tools are X client applications that don't use any windows.

The mechanism described this is used in case the WM is **forcing** a window to close. The normal way is that the WM sends a `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` message to the client, and the client can react to this message in any way it chooses. For example, it can pop up a confirmation dialog ("Really quit this program?"), and if the user confirms, it can clean up everything and exit. This is the recommended behaviour you'll see in most X programming examples. But again, nothing stops the client from completely ignoring this message (in which case the WM can use `xdestroywindow` to force the window to close).